# Terminal completely crashed and stuck after installing zsh and yvm (Cannot type, Ctrl C does not work)

Tags: node.js, terminal, zsh, yarnpkg, oh-my-zsh

After setting up zsh (with `brew install zsh`), I can't type anything in new terminals. I've tried ctrl C, ctrl d, ctrl x, restarting terminal, restarting my computer

When I first installed it, it worked in the terminal window I had open, but after that all new terminal windows were stuck.

This is what I have in settings - I've tried switching between default login shell and command (complete path) for "Shells open with"
[image]

this is what I see when I open terminal:

```
Last login: Mon Aug 12 10:08:24 on ttys001
nodenv: node: command not found

The `node' command exists in these Node versions:
  9.11.1
  12.3.1

Could not get shim path from yvm

[Process completed]
```

I also installed yvm and Oh My Zsh at the same time with:

`brew install tophat/bar/yvm`

and

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

It's also possible that I forgot to run the command to configure `yvm` but I no longer have the history after restarting everything

Unfortunately, I can't type anything in terminal to debug

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get terminal working again by opening my `.zshrc` in VSCode and deleting everything related to `nodenv` and `yvm`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to another answer here, but since this is a new profile I can't add a comment.
I went into .zshrc, commented out the lines the had to do with yvm. After, rebooted my terminal and ran brew update. Then, I re installed yvm, and uncommented out the yvm lines in the .zshrc, rebooted the terminal, and everything worked as normal again.